# List of interesting and useful Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, puzzle

I am in a quest of understanding majority of important algorithm that SO community has used in read world applciations. I know a ready list can be extracted from wiki [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms). But, i am interested only those algorithm or problem that community has faced either in their projects or asked in interviews. Few lines on that algorithm will also be helpful.
I am looking beyond the generic algorithm D&C, DP, Greedy...

Comment: google it; or have a look on glassdoor.com - there are tons of interview questions related to about any algorithm you can think of

Comment: glassdoor is good for taking a peek over employees salaries but is worst if it comes to find some good challenging problems

Comment: if algorithmic challenges are what you are looking for why not try topCoder, hackerrank, codechef or any of the other sites which specialize in competition style coding.

Comment: @Pandrei: Please read the question again. :)

Comment: @Genuine Downvoters:Reason why this question is downvoted? Does this question not comply with SO rules and regulations?

Comment: Yes, it unfortunately doesn't comply. See this post - [What is the definition of a list question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124462/206447)

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to go through [Wikipedia's list of algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms) and decide for yourself which ones are interesting. For the post part, they are all useful in their own ways.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interesting about optimization problems which can be used any computer applications such as network and socket programming these could be useful for you;

- NearbyNeighbour
- Munkres
- Hungarian
- BruteForce
- Min&Max Finding Algorithms
- Ant and Bee Colonies Algorithms
- General Genetic Algorithm etc.

I totally advice you to search all aboves but **genetic algorithms** and **ant colonies algorithm** are asked many interviewers.

I hope that helps.